# style matching words in paragraphs python

Tags: python

lets suppose a search term be `xxx car costs` and i have a paragraphs `this is a xxx brand new car, it costs around $120000`

i want insert a `<strong>` tag around the matching words in paragraphs

What i tried

```
search = 'xxx car costs'
content = 'this is a xxx brand new car, it costs around $120000'
search_terms = search.split()

    for word in search_terms:
        if word not in content: continue
        print('<strong>{}</strong>'.format(word))
```

This gave me matching keyterms from paragraphs :: **xxx** **car** **costs**

The desired result : this is a **xxx** brand new **car**, it **costs** $120000

Comment: Yes, because `if word not in content` **you don't `print` it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach using `str.replace`:

```
for word in search_terms:
   content = content.replace(word, '<strong>'+word+'</strong>')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this instead, it's slightly cleaner imho:

```
search = 'xxx car costs'
content = 'this is a xxx brand new car, it costs around $120000'
search_terms = search.split()

new_content = content
for word in search_terms:
    new_content = new_content.replace(word, '<strong>%s</strong>' % word)

print new_content
```